# uninitialized constant Dalli (NameError) in staging but not production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, memcached, dalli

So I get a `uninitialized constant Dalli (NameError)` when I push my ruby on rails app to my staging on heroku, but it works fine in production. my `production.rb` and `staging.rb` files are the exact same except for a mailer host value. Could someone help? Thanks!

production.rb:

```
Novulty::Application.configure do
  # Settings specified here will take precedence over those in config/application.rb

  # Code is not reloaded between requests
  config.cache_classes = true

  # Full error reports are disabled and caching is turned on
  config.consider_all_requests_local       = false
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = true

  # Enable Rails's static asset server
  config.serve_static_assets = true

  # Compress JavaScripts and CSS
  config.assets.compress = true

  # Compress CSS using yui-compressor gem
  config.assets.css_compressor = :yui

  # Compress JS using uglifier gem
  config.assets.js_compressor = :uglifier

  # Don't fallback to assets pipeline if a precompiled asset is missed
  config.assets.compile = false

  # Generate digests for assets URLs
  config.assets.digest = true

  # Defaults to nil and saved in location specified by config.assets.prefix
  # config.assets.manifest = YOUR_PATH

  # Specifies the header that your server uses for sending files
  # config.action_dispatch.x_sendfile_header = "X-Sendfile" # for apache
  # config.action_dispatch.x_sendfile_header = 'X-Accel-Redirect' # for nginx

  # Force all access to the app over SSL, use Strict-Transport-Security, and use secure cookies.
  config.force_ssl = false

  # See everything in the log (default is :info)
  # config.log_level = :debug

  # Prepend all log lines with the following tags
  # config.log_tags = [ :subdomain, :uuid ]

  # Use a different logger for distributed setups
  # config.logger = ActiveSupport::TaggedLogging.new(SyslogLogger.new)

  # Enable serving of images, stylesheets, and JavaScripts from an asset server
  # config.action_controller.asset_host = "http://assets.example.com"

  # Precompile additional assets (application.js, application.css, and all non-JS/CSS are already added)
  config.assets.precompile += %w[ *.js *.css ]

  # Enable threaded mode
  # config.threadsafe!

  # Enable locale fallbacks for I18n (makes lookups for any locale fall back to
  # the I18n.default_locale when a translation can not be found)
  config.i18n.fallbacks = true

  # Send deprecation notices to registered listeners
  config.active_support.deprecation = :notify

  # Log the query plan for queries taking more than this (works
  # with SQLite, MySQL, and PostgreSQL)
  # config.active_record.auto_explain_threshold_in_seconds = 0.5

  config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true
  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = false
  config.action_mailer.default :charset => "utf-8"

  # Use SMTP to send mail
  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp

  # Use Gmail to send smtp mail
  config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
    :address              => "smtp.gmail.com",
    :port                 => 587,
    :domain               => "novulty.com",
    :user_name            => ENV["GMAIL_USERNAME"],
    :password             => ENV["GMAIL_PASSWORD"],
    :authentication       => :plain,
    :enable_starttls_auto => true
  }

  # Specify what domain to use for mailer URLs
  config.action_mailer.default_url_options = {
    host: "novulty.com"
  }

  # Specify how long an item should stay cached by setting the Cache-Control headers
  config.static_cache_control = "public, max-age=2592000"

  # Specify Dalli as the storage backends for Rails’ built-in Rack::Cache integration
  config.action_dispatch.rack_cache = {
    :metastore    => Dalli::Client.new,
    :entitystore  => 'file:tmp/cache/rack/body',
    :allow_reload => false
  }
end
```

staging.rb:

```
Novulty::Application.configure do
  # Settings specified here will take precedence over those in config/application.rb

  # Code is not reloaded between requests
  config.cache_classes = true

  # Full error reports are disabled and caching is turned on
  config.consider_all_requests_local       = false
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = true

  # Enable Rails's static asset server
  config.serve_static_assets = true

  # Compress JavaScripts and CSS
  config.assets.compress = true

  # Compress CSS using yui-compressor gem
  config.assets.css_compressor = :yui

  # Compress JS using uglifier gem
  config.assets.js_compressor = :uglifier

  # Don't fallback to assets pipeline if a precompiled asset is missed
  config.assets.compile = false

  # Generate digests for assets URLs
  config.assets.digest = true

  # Defaults to nil and saved in location specified by config.assets.prefix
  # config.assets.manifest = YOUR_PATH

  # Specifies the header that your server uses for sending files
  # config.action_dispatch.x_sendfile_header = "X-Sendfile" # for apache
  # config.action_dispatch.x_sendfile_header = 'X-Accel-Redirect' # for nginx

  # Force all access to the app over SSL, use Strict-Transport-Security, and use secure cookies.
  config.force_ssl = false

  # See everything in the log (default is :info)
  # config.log_level = :debug

  # Prepend all log lines with the following tags
  # config.log_tags = [ :subdomain, :uuid ]

  # Use a different logger for distributed setups
  # config.logger = ActiveSupport::TaggedLogging.new(SyslogLogger.new)

  # Enable serving of images, stylesheets, and JavaScripts from an asset server
  # config.action_controller.asset_host = "http://assets.example.com"

  # Precompile additional assets (application.js, application.css, and all non-JS/CSS are already added)
  config.assets.precompile += %w[ *.js *.css ]

  # Enable threaded mode
  # config.threadsafe!

  # Enable locale fallbacks for I18n (makes lookups for any locale fall back to
  # the I18n.default_locale when a translation can not be found)
  config.i18n.fallbacks = true

  # Send deprecation notices to registered listeners
  config.active_support.deprecation = :notify

  # Log the query plan for queries taking more than this (works
  # with SQLite, MySQL, and PostgreSQL)
  # config.active_record.auto_explain_threshold_in_seconds = 0.5

  config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true
  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = false
  config.action_mailer.default :charset => "utf-8"

  # Use SMTP to send mail
  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp

  # Use Gmail to send smtp mail
  config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
    :address              => "smtp.gmail.com",
    :port                 => 587,
    :domain               => "novulty.com",
    :user_name            => ENV["GMAIL_USERNAME"],
    :password             => ENV["GMAIL_PASSWORD"],
    :authentication       => :plain,
    :enable_starttls_auto => true
  }

  # Specify what domain to use for mailer URLs
  config.action_mailer.default_url_options = {
    host: "novultystaging.herokuapp.com"
  }

  # Specify how long an item should stay cached by setting the Cache-Control headers
  config.static_cache_control = "public, max-age=2592000"

  # Specify Dalli as the storage backends for Rails’ built-in Rack::Cache integration
  config.action_dispatch.rack_cache = {
    :metastore    => Dalli::Client.new,
    :entitystore  => 'file:tmp/cache/rack/body',
    :allow_reload => false
  }
end
```

production.rb:

```
require File.expand_path('../boot', __FILE__)

require 'rails/all'

if defined?(Bundler)
  # If you precompile assets before deploying to production, use this line
  Bundler.require(*Rails.groups(:assets => %w(development test)))
  # If you want your assets lazily compiled in production, use this line
  # Bundler.require(:default, :assets, Rails.env)
end

module Novulty
  class Application < Rails::Application
    # Settings in config/environments/* take precedence over those specified here.
    # Application configuration should go into files in config/initializers
    # -- all .rb files in that directory are automatically loaded.

    # Custom directories with classes and modules you want to be autoloadable.
    # config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/extras)

    # Only load the plugins named here, in the order given (default is alphabetical).
    # :all can be used as a placeholder for all plugins not explicitly named.
    # config.plugins = [ :exception_notification, :ssl_requirement, :all ]

    # Activate observers that should always be running.
    # config.active_record.observers = :cacher, :garbage_collector, :forum_observer

    # Set Time.zone default to the specified zone and make Active Record auto-convert to this zone.
    # Run "rake -D time" for a list of tasks for finding time zone names. Default is UTC.
    # config.time_zone = 'Central Time (US & Canada)'

    # Use dalli cache store in production
    config.cache_store = :dalli_store

    # The default locale is :en and all translations from config/locales/*.rb,yml are auto loaded.
    # config.i18n.load_path += Dir[Rails.root.join('my', 'locales', '*.{rb,yml}').to_s]
    # config.i18n.default_locale = :de

    # Add Font-Awesome support (add app/assets/font to the asset path)
    config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join("app", "assets", "fonts")

    # Configure the default encoding used in templates for Ruby 1.9.
    config.encoding = "utf-8"

    # Configure sensitive parameters which will be filtered from the log file.
    config.filter_parameters += [:password]

    # Enable escaping HTML in JSON.
    config.active_support.escape_html_entities_in_json = true

    # Use SQL instead of Active Record's schema dumper when creating the database.
    # This is necessary if your schema can't be completely dumped by the schema dumper,
    # like if you have constraints or database-specific column types
    # config.active_record.schema_format = :sql

    # Enforce whitelist mode for mass assignment.
    # This will create an empty whitelist of attributes available for mass-assignment for all models
    # in your app. As such, your models will need to explicitly whitelist or blacklist accessible
    # parameters by using an attr_accessible or attr_protected declaration.
    config.active_record.whitelist_attributes = true

    # Enable the asset pipeline
    config.assets.enabled = true

    # Version of your assets, change this if you want to expire all your assets
    config.assets.version = '1.0'

    config.assets.initialize_on_precompile = false
  end
end
```

Here is the output of `heroku logs --tail --remote staging`:

```
2012-11-08T02:04:59+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/engine.rb:571:in `block in <class:Engine>'
2012-11-08T02:04:59+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
2012-11-08T02:04:59+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
2012-11-08T02:04:59+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
2012-11-08T02:04:59+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `each'
2012-11-08T02:04:59+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/application.rb:136:in `initialize!'
2012-11-08T02:04:59+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
2012-11-08T02:04:59+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/config/environments/staging.rb:96:in `block in <top (required)>': uninitialized constant Dalli (NameError)
2012-11-08T02:04:59+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:24:in `class_eval'
2012-11-08T02:04:59+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:24:in `configure'
2012-11-08T02:04:59+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/config/environments/staging.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
2012-11-08T02:04:59+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
2012-11-08T02:04:59+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `instance_eval'
2012-11-08T02:04:59+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
2012-11-08T02:04:59+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/config.ru:4:in `require'
2012-11-08T02:04:59+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/config.ru:4:in `block in <main>'
2012-11-08T02:04:59+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/config.ru:1:in `new'
2012-11-08T02:04:59+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/config.ru:1:in `<main>'
2012-11-08T02:04:59+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `eval'
2012-11-08T02:04:59+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `parse_file'
2012-11-08T02:04:59+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/server.rb:200:in `app'
2012-11-08T02:04:59+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `<top (required)>'
2012-11-08T02:04:59+00:00 app[web.1]:   from script/rails:6:in `require'
2012-11-08T02:04:59+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `tap'
2012-11-08T02:04:59+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/commands.rb:55:in `block in <top (required)>'
2012-11-08T02:04:59+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:70:in `start'
2012-11-08T02:04:59+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `initialize'
2012-11-08T02:04:59+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:46:in `app'
2012-11-08T02:04:59+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/server.rb:301:in `wrapped_app'
2012-11-08T02:04:59+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/server.rb:252:in `start'
2012-11-08T02:04:59+00:00 app[web.1]:   from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

Feel free to check out my code at [www.github.com/sambaek/novulty](http://www.github.com/sambaek/novulty)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look at your `Gemfile`:

```
group :production do
  gem 'dalli'
end
```

Bundler does not load Dalli in your staging environment.
Either move it out of the `:production` group, so it's available in all environments, or add it to the `:staging` environment too.

Comment: oh right. that makes sense... how could i miss that. thank you!